# Remainder operation in terms of the floor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came across this identity $$a\bmod{n}= a - \left\lfloor \frac{a}{n} \right\rfloor \times n$$

I see that it works, but I'm struggling to prove it, so I thought I would ask you guys.

Comment: Write $a$ using the division algorithm with $n$ as the dividend.

Comment: Hint: write $a$ as $k * n + b$, where  $\ 0 \leq b < n$.

Comment: Ok, so I need to prove $\displaystyle k=\left\lfloor \frac{a}{n} \right\rfloor$...

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{a}{n}=k+\frac{b}{n}$ with $\displaystyle\frac{b}{n}<1$ so done?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea!

Comment: To be more rigorous, you would have to show that you can indeed write every integer in that form, but I think most mathematicians believe that. And there is probably some well-known lemma for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ as $kn + b$ with $k, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \leq b < n$.

Then $ a = b $ (mod $n$)

and:

$$ nk + b - n\left\lfloor \frac{kn + b}{n}\right\rfloor = nk + b + n\left\lfloor k + \frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor $$

and since $\frac{b}{n} < 1$ because $b < n$ this is equal to:

$$nk + b - n\lfloor k \rfloor = nk + b - nk = b$$